upload picture in google form selenium
I want to upload an image to Google Forms using Selenium.
I’ve managed to open the form and even triggered the file upload dialog box by clicking the “Add file” button. However, when it comes to interacting with the dialog, specifically clicking on the file input button (type="file"), I keep hitting a wall. The button is present in the DOM and visible on the page, but Selenium doesn’t seem to be able to interact with it.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Locating the button – I've located the correct XPath for the "Add file" and file input button.
Waits and delays – I’ve added explicit waits (WebDriverWait) to ensure the elements are loaded before interacting with them.
JavaScript execution – I even attempted executing JavaScript directly to trigger the click event, but that didn’t solve the issue.
Other actions – I've tried switching to the frame or the dialog using switch_to.frame() just in case it’s an iframe, but that approach hasn’t helped either.

So far, I’ve been able to:

Open the Google Form.
Click the "Add file" button successfully.
Wait for the popup to appear. But I’m stuck at trying to upload the image itself.

I’m open to any suggestions, whether it’s about tweaking the current approach or trying something entirely different.
import undetected_chromedriver as webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

# Configuration des options de Chrome
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile = r"C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 1"
options.add_argument(f"user-data-dir={profile}")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 1")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)

try:
    driver.get("https://forms.gle/HcKLXz9ErXkm63qK8")
    print("Formulaire ouvert avec succès.")

    # Cliquer sur le bouton 'Add file'
    add_file_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/span/span[2]'))
    )
    add_file_button.click()
    print("Bouton 'Add file' cliqué avec succès.")

    # Attendre que le popup apparaisse
    popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]'))  # XPath du popup
    )
    print("Popup visible.")

    # Localiser le bouton 'Browser' à l'intérieur du popup
    browser_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]//button[@aria-label="Browser"]'))  # XPath du bouton 'Browser'
    )

    # Utiliser ActionChains pour s'assurer que le bouton est interactif
    action = ActionChains(driver)
    action.move_to_element(browser_button).click().perform()
    print("Bouton 'Browser' cliqué avec succès.")

    # Attendre que la boîte de dialogue de téléchargement soit ouverte
    file_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@type="file"]'))  # XPath de l'élément de saisie de fichier
    )
    
    # Upload de l'image
    file_path = "./01.png"
    file_input.send_keys(file_path)
    print(f"Image téléchargée avec succès : {file_path}")

    # Soumettre le formulaire
    submit_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/button'))
    )
    submit_button.click()
    print("Formulaire soumis avec succès.")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Erreur: {e}")
finally:
    driver.quit()


Can you share the error stack trace that you're getting after execution of the program?

I know this is ancient history but have you looked Python-Selenium "input type file" upload? Ditto Importing image to google forms via selenium driver in python
